# Optimización de código de simulación para reducir tiempo de ejecución

Tags: python-3.x, revisión-de-código

He creado el siguiente código para simular un proceso de explotación de recursos por parte de una población de agentes. Comparto con la comunidad el código del modelo abajo.

El código tiene una clase `class Actions` que contiene las acciones de los agentes, una función `def agent_type` que define cómo los agentes toman decisiones y otra función `def scenario` donde se calculan las medias de eficiencia, recursos existentes y consumindos por la población a lo largo del tiempo.

Mi objetivo sería optimizar este código. Estoy seguro que hay maneras de hacerlo correr más rápidamente. Ahora mismo, si aumento el tamaño de la población `N`, el tiempo de simulación es muy alto.

Agradecería ayuda para optimizar este código y hacerlo más rápido.

Este es el código del modelo:

```
import numpy as np

class Actions:
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.mean = 0
        self.t = 0

    def choose(self):
        return np.random.randn() + self.m

    def update(self, x):
        self.t += 1
        self.mean = (1 - 1.0 / self.t) * self.mean + 1.0 / self.t * x

def agent_type(m1, m2, m3, m4, eps, t, bs, rebound):
    actions = [Actions(m1), Actions(m2), Actions(m3), Actions(m4)]
    data = np.empty(t)
    data_2 = np.empty(t)

    for i in range(t):
            if i <= 1:
                x = 0
                resources_consumed_by_agent = bs
            else:
                p = np.random.random()
                if p < eps:
                    j = np.random.choice(4)
                else:
                    j = np.argmax([a.mean for a in actions])
                x = actions[j].choose()
                actions[j].update(x)
                resources_consumed_by_agent = bs + (x * rebound) - (1 - rebound) * x
                resources_consumed_by_agent = np.clip(resources_consumed_by_agent, 0, None)

            data[i] = x
            data_2[i] = resources_consumed_by_agent

    efficiency = np.cumsum(data) / (np.arange(t) + 1)
    efficiency = np.clip(efficiency, 0, None)
    consumption = np.cumsum(data_2) / (np.arange(t) + 1)
    return efficiency, consumption


# Running scenarios
def scenario(m1, m2, m3, m4, eps, t, N, bs, r_t0, rep_rate, rebound):
    a = []
    r = []

    for agent in range(N):
        agent = agent_type(m1, m2, m3, m4, eps, t, bs, rebound)
        a.append(agent[0])
        r.append(agent[1])
    mean_eff_pop = np.mean(a, 0)
    mean_consumption_pop = np.round(np.mean(r, 0),2)
    total_consumption_pop = np.add.reduce(r)
    existing_resources = [r_t0]
    prior = existing_resources[0]
    for n in total_consumption_pop:
        prior = (prior - n) * (1 + rep_rate)
        prior = np.clip(prior, 0, r_t0)
        existing_resources.append(prior)
    existing_resources = [max(min(y, r_t0), 0) for y in existing_resources]


    return mean_eff_pop, existing_resources, mean_consumption_pop
```

Éste es el script desde donde importo el modelo, con un ejemplo de simulación:

```
from modelo import scenario
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import string
import random


# Parameters
a_effic = [0, 1, 2, 3]
t = 10000
N = 10
eps = [0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5]
bs = 0.1
r_t0 = 1000
rep_rate = 0.01
rebound = 0.9

# Scenarios
c_5 = scenario(a_effic[0], a_effic[1], a_effic[2], a_effic[3], eps[4], t, N, bs, r_t0, rep_rate, rebound)
```

Comment: La complejidad computacional esta determinada por `t * N`, aumentas estos parámetros y los tiempos se multiplicarán. ¿Se podría optimizar esto de manera significativa? seguramente se pueden hacer mejoras, pero lo significativo es que puedas evitar el uso de los loops anidados, lamentablemente sin entender que es lo que buscas y como lo has implementado, es difícil por no decir imposible, sugerirte algo.

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho, en efecto el código simula una población de N agentes a lo largo de una serie de pasos discretos de tiempo t. No se me ocurre forma de evitar el loop anidado. En el fondo se trata de simular una población a lo largo del tiempo t, por lo que que lógicamente, al aumentar el tiempo o el tamaño poblacional, el tiempo de simulación aumenta como t * N. En cualquier caso, gracias por el comentario !!

Comment: Por lo que dices, creo entonces que cualquier optimización que hagas al código va a ser marginal, el problema no es tanto la implementación sino el algoritmo en sí mismo.  Desconozco el dominio de tu problema, pero si puedo comentarte que muchas veces con problemas de este tipo, puede haber aproximaciones "heurísticas",  más óptimas aunque no tan exactas.

Answer (score 1):

encontré varias cosas:

- Ordené un poco el código ya que enviar por posición varias parámentros es todo un dolor de cabeza cuando son más de 3 argumentos que recibe la función, así que lo coloqué dentro de un diccionario para que quede un poco más limpio.
- Me parece que tiene un error en la línea `for agent in range(N):` ya que en la siguiente iteración está reemplazando por el elemento que llega de `agent_type` así que puede convertirse en un bug
- En la línea `if p < data['eps']:` está comparando el arreglo `data['eps']` con el número aleatorio que viene de `p = np.random.random()`
- En la línea `actions = [Actions(data['a_effic'][0]), Actions(data['a_effic'][1]), Actions(data['a_effic'][2]), Actions(data['a_effic'][3])]` ¿no será mejor colocar directamente el número hacia el constructor? sería algo como: `actions = [Actions(0), Actions(1), Actions(2), Actions(3)]` Eso dependerá de lo que para ud representen estos números o se se cambiarán en el futuro.
- La demora en la iteración es porque técnicamente un for anidado lo cual genera un procesamiento exponencial de O2 así que a no ser que cambie la forma de procesar la información no se puede hacer mucho al respecto.

código un poco mejorado:

```
class Actions:
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.mean = 0
        self.t = 0

    def choose(self):
        return np.random.randn() + self.m

    def update(self, x):
        self.t += 1
        self.mean = (1 - 1.0 / self.t) * self.mean + 1.0 / self.t * x



def agent_type(data):
    actions = [Actions(data['a_effic'][0]), Actions(data['a_effic'][1]), Actions(data['a_effic'][2]), Actions(data['a_effic'][3])]
    data_1 = np.empty(data['t'])
    data_2 = np.empty(data['t'])

    for i in range(data['t']):
        if i <= 1:
            x = 0
            resources_consumed_by_agent = data['bs']
        else:
            p = np.random.random()
            if p < data['eps']:
                j = np.random.choice(len(actions))
            else:
                j = np.argmax([a.mean for a in actions])
            x = actions[j].choose()
            actions[j].update(x)
            resources_consumed_by_agent = data['bs'] + (x * data['rebound']) - (1 - data['rebound']) * x
            resources_consumed_by_agent = np.clip(resources_consumed_by_agent, 0, None)
        data_1[i] = x
        data_2[i] = resources_consumed_by_agent

    efficiency = np.cumsum(data) / (np.arange(data['t']) + 1)
    efficiency = np.clip(efficiency, 0, None)
    consumption = np.cumsum(data_2) / (np.arange(data['t']) + 1)
    return efficiency, consumption


# Running scenarios
def scenario(data):
    a = []
    r = []

    for agent_iter in range(data["N"]):
        agent = agent_type(data)
        a.append(agent[0])
        r.append(agent[1])
    mean_eff_pop = np.mean(a, 0)
    mean_consumption_pop = np.round(np.mean(r, 0),2)
    total_consumption_pop = np.add.reduce(r)
    existing_resources = [data['r_t0']]
    prior = existing_resources[0]
    for n in total_consumption_pop:
        prior = (prior - n) * (1 + data['rep_rate'])
        prior = np.clip(prior, 0, data['r_t0'])
        existing_resources.append(prior)
    existing_resources = [max(min(y, data['r_t0']), 0) for y in existing_resources]

    return mean_eff_pop, existing_resources, mean_consumption_pop

# Parameters
data = {
    "a_effic": [0, 1, 2, 3],
    "t": 10000,
    "N": 10,
    "eps": [0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5],
    "bs": 0.1,
    "r_t0": 1000,
    "rep_rate": 0.01,
    "rebound": 0.9
}

# Scenarios
c_5 = scenario(data)
```

Por favor colocar en su archivo correspondiente ya que lo moví a un único archivo por facilidad.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Parece que hay un error de comparación en el código que compartes: line 32, in agent_type
    if p < data['eps']: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'list'

Comment: Efectivamente, esta comparando p con  una lista. Pero creo que el concepto se entiende. Sé que puede mejorarlo porque no corrí la aplicación